# How to get a complete stack trace of a running java program that is taking 100% cpu?

Tags: java, debugging, stack-trace

I do have a jenkins instance that is stuck in some kind of endless loop without any visible activity.

I can get the `pid` of the running process so how do I generate a trace that I can use for a bug report?

I'm running on linux.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try with [jstack](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html). It'll give you a full list of what your threads are doing. All it needs is the process pid.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps in my case, but it does respond the question http://pastebin.com/r1e0dtzp

Comment: It narrows it down to some extent. If you have 100% CPU usage, you want to be looking for threads that are not in the BLOCKING state. For example Thread 30609 is sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait which could potentially match [this defect](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRMINA-678) depending on your config.

Comment: Recently jstack stopped working and I am not sure why. Here is the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179544/did-the-jstack-stopped-working-on-newer-jdk8-versions

Comment: >NOTE - This utility is unsupported and may or may not be available in future versions of the J2SE SDK. **jstack is not currently available on Windows platforms** or on the Linux Itanium platform.

Answer (score 12):

Take a thread dump. Connect through Visual VM and request a dump. Or if on unix then *kill -3 pid* or on windows *Ctrl+Break* on the process console would do it for you. The dump goes straight to the console. You can also use jstack to throw a dump.

Comment: kill -3 pid works great, thanks!
For those that have a JVM running in "screen": ctrl-a H (uppercase) starts/stops logging to a file.

Comment: `kill -3` worked for me when `jstack` didn't. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`Ctrl+\` on linux (which sends `SIGQUIT`)

`Ctrl+Break` on windows (which sends `SIGBREAK` under MSVCRT)

Answer (score 4):

In *nix, with `top` by pressing `H`  you can see the threads.

Then with `jps` you can see the `pid` bear in mind that if the process was started with privileges then you must execute it with `sudo` for instance.

If you take the thread id and converted it to hexadecimal then you can cross that data with the `jstack pid` output.

Both tools are in `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). There is a lot of nice profiling tools with it, and you can perform a thread dump.