# Suppress Java Ctrl+Break behavior

Tags: java, dump, thread-dump

Java (at least versions 7 and 8 which I have tried) has a default behavior where when it receives a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> signal, it writes out a full thread dump. Is there some way to disable this or suppress this output?

Comment: This is not an exception being fired. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756105/how-to-get-a-complete-stack-trace-of-a-running-java-program-that-is-taking-100. That said, "stack dump" is the wrong term, it dumps all threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Non-Standard Options section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABHDABI) of the manual for the `java` command, you can use the `-Xrs` option to disable it:

> **-Xrs**
>
> Reduces the use of operating system signals by the JVM.
>
> …
>
> There are two consequences of specifying `-Xrs`:
>
> - Ctrl + Break thread dumps are not available.
> - User code is responsible for causing shutdown hooks to run, for example, by calling `System.exit()` when the JVM is to be terminated.

As with all `-X` and `-XX` options, this is not guaranteed to be available in future Java releases.